# Value method called not returned

Tags: objective-c, rest, return-value

I have this class that performs a REST call .

```
- (NSString*)cerca:(NSString*)email{
if ([[Utility sharedUtility] connected]) {
    HttpClient *self = [HttpClient sharedHTTPClient];
    [self.requestSerializer setValue:[self getUserAgent] forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
    [self.requestSerializer setValue:NST_CODE forHTTPHeaderField:@"Nst-Code"];
    [self.requestSerializer setValue:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"nst_id"] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Nst-Id"];
    [self.requestSerializer setValue:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"api_key"] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Api-Key"];

    NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    parameters[@"email"] = email;

    __block NSString *result;

    [self POST:@"get_info" parameters:parameters
       success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {

          result = responseObject;


       } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {


       }]; 
return result;

}
```

The call returns a JSON . My problem is that when I do return result ; Nothing is passed to the calling method .
Can you tell me why ??

The calling method is

```
HttpClient *client = [HttpClient alloc];
NSString *result = [client cerca:email];
```

Comment: The method `self POST:parameters:success:failure` is a asynchronous method, this code `return result` will execute before result is set to `responseObject`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That method you are calling is an asynchronous call, meaning the result comes after you have returned. You need to change your method to accept a block argument and return the result in the callback.

```
- (void)cerca:(NSString*)email callback:(void (^)(id result)) callback {
   if ([[Utility sharedUtility] connected]) {
     ...

     [self POST:@"get_info" parameters:parameters
     success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
        if (callback) { 
          callback(responseObject)
        }
     } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {


     }]; 
  }
}
```

To call the method you would do:

```
[client cerca:email completion:^(NSString *response) {
   // Do what you want with the response.
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because the `self POST` call is asynchronous and you are returning the `result` before it has had time to be assigned. You need to rebuild your `- (NSString*)cerca:(NSString*)email` method so it somehow can handle the asynchronousness of this. Easiest way is usually to change the method so it takes a completion block as in parameter. Maybe something like:

```
        - (void)cerca:(NSString *)email completion:(void (^)(NSString *res))completion {
            [self POST:@"get_info" parameters:parameters success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
                if (completion) {
                    completion(responseObject);
                }
            }failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
                if (completion){
                    completion(nil);
                }
            }];
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed my method

```
- (NSString*)cerca:(NSString*)email completion:(void (^)(NSString *res))completion {
```

But I do not understand what to call it . Indications ?

```
[client cerca:email completion:nil];
```